# File is not uploading when there are multiple fields in model form

Tags: python, django, filefield

I am unable to upload file if there are multiple fields in my model other than file field. I didn't get any error on the page but the page simply displays same page without uploading of my image.

Here is my model

```
class ImageUpload(models.Model):
   username = models.ForeignKey(User)
   imagefile = models.FileField(upload_to='pictures')
   isapproved = models.BooleanField()
   class Meta:
       db_table = u'imageupload'

   def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s' % (self.imagefile)
```

Here is my model form

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self,user, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UploadImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['username'] = forms.CharField(initial = user,
                                       widget = forms.TextInput(
                                     attrs = {'readonly':'readonly'}))
   class Meta:
       model = ImageUpload
       exclude = ('id', 'isapproved')
```

Here is my view where I am handling the data.

```
def imageupload(request):
# Handle file upload
   if request.method == 'POST':
      list = ["jpeg", "jpg","JPG","JPEG","png","PNG"]
      format = imghdr.what(request.FILES['imagefile'])
      if format not in list:
          error = "Please upload a valid file format"
          form = UploadImageForm(request.user)
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myview.views.imageupload'))
      else:
          form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():
              newdoc = ImageUpload(imagefile = request.FILES['imagefile'])
              newdoc.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myview.views.imageupload'))
  else:
      form = UploadImageForm(request.user) # A empty, unbound form
  documents = ImageUpload.objects.all()
  return render_to_response('imageupload.html',
       {'documents': documents, 'form': form,'media':settings.MEDIA_URL},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
   )
```

It used to work properly when I have used only file field in the Model Form. After adding more fields to the model, its not uploading the file. Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance
`Vikram`

Comment: Are you actually displaying the form errors in the template? It seems to me that the `username` field is unlikely to be valid.

Comment: I am not displaying any errors moreover i tried displaying but no errors displayed

Comment: Do we need to give any instance of `User` object for saving the form?

Comment: On a side note: you shouldn't be naming something `list` - and I'd personally use `if re.match('(?i)(jpe?g)|(png)', format) is None`

Comment: There is no problem with that code. Since I have tested it with valid and invalid file formats when my model form has only one filefield

Comment: I wasn't saying it was a problem - just a hint to how to improve that part

Comment: Thanks jon, once my problem is fixed, I will implement your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an else block to your view for form validation. I think that your form is not valid and you do not just print any errors in your template.

```
if form.is_valid():
    newdoc = ImageUpload(imagefile = request.FILES['imagefile'])
    newdoc.save()
else:
    # do something visible here
```

Also if your form is valid you could just use `form.save()` to save the image and the related data instead of creating new `ImageUpload` object.

Also, your model requires the `User` object to be saved.